# Copy rows range from Sheet1 to Sheet2 in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy

My excel data is feeding from other real time application source. My requirement is I want to copy range A1:M20 periodically from Sheet1 to Sheet2. In Sheet2 append new rows(not overwritten). Someone help me to do in excel VBA/

Comment: You have a nice reputation, you should know that we need to see some effort from you. What have you tried and what happened?

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Range("A1:M20")) Is Nothing Then

    Dim NextRow As Range
    Set NextRow = Sheet3.Range("A" & Sheet2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    Sheet1.Range("A1:M20").Copy
    Sheet2.Activate
    NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Set NextRow = Nothing
    
End If
End Sub

Comment: I tried above code, nothing nothing working. And I dont have basic idea about VBA.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer after long search. Here it is.

```
Sub copyData()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    lr = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
    Range("A2:F" & lr).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    lrTarget = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
    Cells(lrTarget + 1, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("A:F").AutoFit
    Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```